# Regex- Allow * in the beginning and in the end of a string and allow only *

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to write a regex that validates the input for a city.
Except for characters only spaces are allowed and * acts as a wildcard character, so it can be either in the end or in the beginning of the string. * character should be allowed to be the only input as well.

Accepted strings:

- `*city`
- `*cit *`
- `'*'`  (only asterisk)
- `*city one`

Not accepted strings:

- `**`
- `*!@`
- `%^&*`

I have written this, but it doesn't allow only `'*"` as input. Any ideas?
`'^.*[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ž ]{1,34}.*$'`

Comment: Note that if your regex needs to use `*` as a literal character it needs to be escaped in most cases, i.e. `\*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex that might be shorter and efficient:

```
^(?:\*?[\p{L}\h]+\*?|\*)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2YEVgZ/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `\*?`: Match an optional `*`
  - `[\p{L}\h]+`: Match 1+ of any unicode letter or horizontal whitespace
  - `\*?`: Match an optional `*`
  - `|`: OR
  - `\*`: Match a single `*`
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `$`: End

**Java Code:**

```
final String regex = "^(?:\\*?[\\p{L}\\h]+\\*?|\\*)$";
String s = "* cit *";
System.out.println( s.matches(regex) );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
^(?:\*|\*?\p{L}+(?:\h+\p{L}*)*+\*?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zbJ04F/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\*|\*?\p{L}+(?:\h+\p{L}*)*+\*?)` - either of the two patterns:

  - `\*` - an asterisk
  - `|` - or
  - `\*?` - an optional asterisk
  - `\p{L}+` - one or more letters
  - `(?:\h+\p{L}*)*+` - one or more repetitions of one or more horizontal whitespaces followed with zero or more letters
  - `\*?` - an optional asterisk
- `$` - end of string.

In Java:

```java
bool matched = text.matches("\\*|\\*?\\p{L}+(?:\\h+\\p{L}*)*+\\*?");
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the asterisk with a backslash so that it isn't interpreted as a greedy repetition quantifier: `\*`.

Use beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors to ensure that your asterisk can only occur at the start or end of the string.

Lastly, use a negative lookahead (`(?!...)`) to ensure that the match can't only be two asterisks.

Putting it all together, you get:

`(?!^\*\*$)^\*?[\p{L} ]*\*?$`